# The undefeatable enemy

Tags: riddle, video-games

Part of a gang of three
More elusive than my brothers
Get close to us and you will see
You can catch a glimpse of me

I'm an infamous enemy of lower rank
When you're near us, I'm visible for one frame
When you leave my brothers, I don't exist
I'm untouchable, unless you play god

I am undefeatable by mortals, no matter what you do
You will never get my precious gold!
You will never catch me alive!
For I am at death's door

Who am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I belive you are referring to

> The Mystery Goomba, from Super Mario 64, which if I recall correctly spawns below the death plane.

Part of a gang of three
More elusive than my brothers

> Goomba's tend to spawn in groups of 3, but this one appears to be only 2 at first.

Get close to us and you will see
You can catch a glimpse of me

> The Mystery Goomba is visible for but a frame after becoming active.

I'm an infamous enemy of lower rank
When you're near us, I'm visible for one frame

> Goombas are low-rank enemies I guess, and this guy dies almost immediately.

When you leave my brothers, I don't exist
I'm untouchable, unless you play god

> I think this guy is only reachable through some sort of edit mode? I don't really remember all the details out of the video I saw.

I am undefeatable by mortals, no matter what you do
You will never get my precious gold!

> Mario can't reach the Mystery Goomba to kill him, and the coins he'd spawn are death are some of the last theoretical coins that haven't been collected.

You will never catch me alive!
For I am at death's door

> Lasts only a frame, because he's below the Death Plane

Comment: Some corrections: the goomba doesn't actually die, he spawns on top of the death plane because there is no ground for him to spawn on. He's just outside Mario's "visibility" radius, thus he becomes invisible and won't move. Since Mario needs to be in the spawn point of the three goombas for the game to load them AND within the visibility radius of the mystery goomba for him to be able to interact with it, you'd have to essentially be in two places at once at the same time.

Comment: Also, "play god" refers to the fact that you can only interact with the goomba if you're hacking the game, for example if you made ground appear for the goomba to spawn on. Someone without hacks (a mere "mortal") can't ever hope to even touch the goomba.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a crack at it, but I don't think this is the one.

> The [Gold Greenie](https://www.mariowiki.com/Gold_Greenie) from Luigi's Mansion: Dark Moon. The Gold Greenie is one of the three variants of the Greenie enemy, along with the regular Greenie and the Strong Greenie. They're rarer (more elusive), hide in furniture that you have to approach to interact with; and since they're ghosts, you obviously can't take them "alive". You might also argue that, since you don't *fight* Gold Greenies, and you only suck them up in the vacuum, you technically never "defeat" them in the conventional sense.

Second guess:

> The [Gold Mouse](https://www.mariowiki.com/Gold_Mouse) from the original Luigi's Mansion. Gold Mice are relatives of the floor-crawling Blue Mice and the wall-crawling Purple Mice. They appear rarely, carry lots of gold, and do nothing but run once they're discovered. And since they, too, are ghosts, the same detail about "never catch me alive" applies.

Comment: Sorry to say, but wrong. You are in the right franchise though. :) I get the feeling my riddle is a bit too broad...

Comment: @noClue I had a feeling the franchise was right, though is LM considered a spinoff from the SM franchise, or are they considered the same franchise?

Comment: I was actually talking about the SM franchise as a whole, not LM as a spinoff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about:

> Erik, one of the 3 vikings from The Lost Vikings

Part of a gang of three

> There is 3 of them

More elusive than my brothers

> Erik is the fastest.

Get close to us and you will see

> You need to select Erik

You can catch a glimpse of me

> And control him to see him dashing through the screen

I am undefeatable

> At least he thinks so

You will never get my precious gold!

> Not sure about this bit

You will never catch me alive!

> He always tries to use his speed to get away of the traps.

For I am at death's door

> But not always succeeds.

Comment: Interesting answer, but no cigar!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is

> Reptile from Mortal Kombat

Part of a gang of three

> His original design was the same as Scorpion and Sub-Zero, except for color

More elusive than my brothers

> It was originally a hidden character in the game

Get close to us and you will see
You can catch a glimpse of me

> He has a hybrid of the attacks of both Scorpion and Sub-Zero

I'm an infamous enemy of lower rank
When you're near us, I'm visible for one frame

> He was often invisible

When you leave my brothers, I don't exist
I'm untouchable, unless you play god

> He was unplayable in the 1st game.  I presume that he was playable if the game were in God mode

I am undefeatable by mortals, no matter what you do
You will never get my precious gold!
You will never catch me alive!
For I am at death's door

> Here is where my guess breaks down, unless there's history I'm unaware of

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to this site, and not skilled as others who have replied before me. But I would like to take a shot at it too.

I only focused on the riddle you wrote in your first posting:

> Either you are the second-hand on a clock, or "tomorrow."

When you said "you will never get my precious gold!" I took it as a hyperbole.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! Please post a reason/answer to every part of the riddle, and not just a short part. Also, please include spoiler tags to hide your answers from potential solvers. Take the tour to learn more and earn a badge!

Comment: @PuzzledPig tyvm for editing it for me, I did not know how to when writing it. 
NL628 - I tried to find the spoiler tag option, but the list of options were not clear enough to distinguish which one it was. That's also one of the reasons why I didn't dive deep in to the riddle to give others a chance. Thanks for the info, I hope to learn more when I get the time. Cheers!

Comment: The tour that NL628 mentioned is [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour), if you're interested!  And I assume you checked the edit history on your post to see how to do spoilers - it's the characters >! before any line you want to hide :)